# Selecting rows where column is not null and equal to a (string) value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection, pandas-loc

So basically I want select all rows where Col A is equal to the string 'hey'.
My problem is that Col A can contain null/nan's therefore I get a

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison.
```

When executing:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'hey']
```

I then made another condition:

```
df.loc[df['A'].notnull() & (df['A'] == 'hey')]
```

Here i get the same error.

I made a hack where I change all the null values in Col A to '' but thats not beautiful is there anyway nice to first choose all the rows where Col A isn't null and then from there all the ones who are equal to 'hey'?

Comment: df.loc[df['A'] .astype(str) == 'hey']  is working. Thanks Jezrael

Answer (score 1):

I guess there should be some numeric, so try convert values to `string`s or compare numpy array:

```
newDf = df[df.A.astype(str) == 'hey']
```

Or:

```
newDf = df[df.A.values == 'hey']
```

Comment: Hey man! Thanks the conversion to .astype(str) worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
newDf = df[df.A == 'hey']
```

This should give you a new dataframe with all rows that contained "hey" from column A?

Comment: No because you can't compare a string and a null value. Thats why my first solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For null / NaN values, your logic is fine. Below is an example. You should provide a minimal and verifiable example, indicating version numbers for Python / Pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [np.nan, None, 'hey', 45.4352, 'somestring']})

print(df.loc[df['col'] == 'hey'])

   col
2  hey
```